# Can't run Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working on an website as a final project at school. I have been struggling with this problem, I can't run JavaScript function in the HTML. You have an example of my work here. I expect the output after clicking the button to be "correct" or "incorrect". Please help, thank you so much!

```html
<div>What is my name?</div>
<input id="name" value="your answer here" />
<br></br>
<button onclick="check()">Check your answers here</button>

<script>
  function check() {
    var name, a_name;
    name = getElementById("name").value;
    a_name = (name === "Clark") ? "correct" : "incorrect"
    document.write(a_name);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should use the selectors properly. It is [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this below code snippet...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function check() {
      var name, a_name;
      name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      a_name = (name === "Clark") ? "correct": "incorrect"
      document.write(a_name);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>What is my name?</div>
    <input id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your value" />
    <br></br>
    <button onclick="check()">Check your answers here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

you forgot to add the `document` before the `getElementById`